# What to do when ActiveMQ's queue is full in productive environment?

Tags: java, queue, activemq-classic

This is an interview question - what to do when ActiveMQ's queue is full in productive environment?

Should the next messages be discarded; or should I implement a buffer myself or store it in DB?

I want to know the general solution in real productive environment.

Comment: Scale out whatever process is dequeuing the messages.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is: it depends.

On **your** requirements. Which we can't know. You have to understand which of the various approaches meets the businesses goals of your application.

In other words: there can't be a a general answer. If you are measuring clicks on some web page, it might not be a big deal to loose one. But when we are talking about an order from a customer you better make sure to never forget about a single one.

Comment: Ok,thanks . To be honest , it's an interview question and I'm not sure about my answers . When MQ is used to Decoupling multiple systems , messages are important right? In this case , what's the detailed solution?like implementing a buffer myself or storing it in DB ? But I think storing in DB is not efficient right?

Comment: Again it depends. When you implement an in memory buffer, you can still loose events when your system crashes! So writing into persistent storage might be a better strategy to avoid loosing data. On the other hand that could mean that you start putting load onto your database in situations where something is already going amiss, thus making your problems worse!

Comment: @tom redfern,this is just an interview question collected from Internet.I'm preparing for looking a new job , but I'm not in an interview...

Comment: Not sure what else to say here. Your question is pretty broad, so you can actually be happy it didn't get downvoted /closed on you. And I doubt that much else will be coming. So, just for the record,consider accepting at some point.

Comment: coming for what , so disgusting